# function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^3$ which is $C^3$ but not $C^4$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'd like to find an example of a function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^3$ which is $C^3$ but not $C^4$. Also, I need a proof.

I have $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))$ and I need the third derivative not to be continuous, for instance.

Comment: For $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = x^3|x|$ is $C^3$ but not $C^4$ (for proof, see a pattern in the derivative). Use this to create something for your situation.

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: You are welcome, BB98.